# Detection of abnormally rapid jumps in the graph

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I have some problems with detect fast up moving curve in dataset.
Example of dataset:
6500 (integer value), 2013-04-16 15:31 (date time value or timestamp in milliseconds)
6480, 2013-04-16 15:31
6480, 2013-04-16 15:32
6450, 2013-04-16 15:33
6430, 2013-04-16 15:34
6410, 2013-04-16 15:35
...
2110, 2013-04-26 1:56

This array of data forms a graph:
[image]

I need help with the detection of abnormally rapid jumps in the graph, for example - detect the start and end points of lines that are painted black:
[image]

Best solution, as it seemed to me - **[use gradients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient)** or local **[maxima and minima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima)**, but I do not understand how to apply it to solve this problem.

I would be grateful for any hint or for any piece of code algorithm (in any languages), thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your rapid jumps are jumps up rather than jump down.  If you data set is V[i] for `0<=i<n`, you just need to look at whether V[i] - V[i-1] > T where T = some threshhold to detect the jump.  So it's all a question about how to set the T.  I'd suggest that the threshold also varies, so it's T[i] rather than a fixed number T.  For example, you could make T[i] = M C[i] where C[i] is an exponentially weighted moving average of the recent changes, i.e.

C[i] = C[i-1] * (1 - W) + W * Abs(V[i-1] - V[i-2])

Here, if W=1, then C[i] is always the most recent change, but with W<1 it does an average of recent changes, with the most recent change carrying the most weight.  The multipler M could be e.g. 2, meaning you're looking for double the jump of the exponentially weighted moving average of the recent changes.  Something along those lines should work :-)

Comment: Or, for that matter, `|V[i] - V[i-1]| > T` to detect jumps in either direction.  But your point of measuring the deviation of the current observation from the running average is the better answer.  +1